# Issue with KotlinPair after updating to Kotlin 1.4.10

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I updated Kotlin Multiplatform project from Kotlin 1.3.72 to 1.4.10 and when I tried to built the code I got issues like:

- LocationStepCardView.swift:13:19: Reference to generic type 'KotlinPair' requires arguments in <...>
- LocationStepCardView.swift:28:24: Generic class 'KotlinPair' requires that 'Double' be a class type

When I rollback to branch without update to kotlin 1.4.10, everything is working fine.

Code:

commonMain.kt

```
interface LocationView {
var location: Pair<Latitude, Longitude>?

fun setOnSavingLocationPermissionProceedAction(action: () -> Unit)
fun setOnSavingLocationPermissionSkipAction(action: () -> Unit)
fun setOnSavingLocationPermissionAllowAction(action: (Pair<Latitude, Longitude>?) -> Unit)
fun setOnSavingLocationPermissionDenyAction(action: () -> Unit)
}
```

LatitudeCommon.kt

```
inline class Latitude(val value: Double)
```

LongitudeCommon.kt

```
inline class Longitude(val value: Double)
```

LocationStepCardView.swift

```
import kotlinProjectCommon

extension LocationStepCardView: LocationView {

var location: KotlinPair? {
    get { currentLocation as? KotlinPair }
    set { currentLocation = newValue }
}

func setOnSavingLocationPermissionProceedAction(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
    proceedAction = action
}

func setOnSavingLocationPermissionSkipAction(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
    skipAction = action
}

func setOnSavingLocationPermissionAllowAction(action: @escaping (KotlinPair?) -> Void) {
    onLocationUpdateAction = { (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) in
        let pair = KotlinPair(first: latitude, second: longitude)
        action(pair)
    }
}

func setOnSavingLocationPermissionDenyAction(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
    onDeniedLocationAction = action
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess because Objective-C generics are now enabled by default. You can disable them with `-Xno-objc-generics`.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/objc_interop.html#generics

As for "needs to be a class type", I assume that means you need to explicitly convert to `KotlinDouble`. Disabling generics *may* revert that issue, but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. This solved one of the problems related to building the application.